# Is there any meaningful notion of a probability distribution for the number of quark-antiquark pairs in a hadron?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, virtual-particles, protons

A hadron (such a proton) can be thought of as being composed of a large (but fluctuating) number of quark-antiquark pairs. As far as I understand it, the situation (say for a proton, for definiteness) is roughly the following:

We have an "up quark number operator" $\hat{Q}_\text{up} := \hat{N}_\text{up primary quarks} - \hat{N}_\text{up antiquarks}$, and likewise for down quarks. (By "primary" quark, I mean a quark that is not an antiquark.) The proton ground state is a simultaneous exact eigenstate of $\hat{Q}_\text{up}$ (with eigenvalue 2) and of $\hat{Q}_\text{down}$ (with eigenvalue 1). But it is *not* an eigenstate of $\hat{N}_\text{up primary quark}$ or of $\hat{N}_\text{up antiquark}$ individually. So the number of up primary and antiquarks is indefinite, even though those values are entangled in such a way that their difference is always exactly 2 (and likewise the down quark number is always exactly 1). Is this picture correct?

If so, then it seems like you could define a probability distribution over the number of up quark-antiquark pairs given by $p_n(\text{up}) := |\langle \text{$n$ up antiquarks}|\text{proton}\rangle|^2$, where $|\text{$n$ up antiquarks}\rangle$ denotes an eigenstate of $\hat{N}_\text{up antiquark}$ with eigenvalue $n$ and $|\text{proton}\rangle$ denotes the proton ground state. And similarly for the down quarks. Is this correct?

I suspect there are many subtleties that I'm sweeping under the rug, and the number operators $\hat{N}_\text{up primary quarks}$ and $\hat{N}_\text{up antiquarks}$ are not uniquely defined. But is there any sense (even an approximate one) in which which I've said is correct, and if so, has anyone attempted to actually calculate the probability distributions $p_n(\text{up})$ and $p_n(\text{down})$ for the proton, or for another hadron? (I understand that such a calculation would probably enormously difficult, and could only be done approximately using lattice QCD.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this would differ from the parton distribution functions?

Comment: Or rather, multiparton distribution functions -- maybe those are in fact what you are interested in?

Comment: @jwimberley I don't really understand exactly what parton distribution functions actually represent, but from what I gather, they tell you something like the fraction of the total hadron energy that comes from various contributions. But I'm interested in the non-normalized absolute number of virtual particles (if such a concept even makes sense), not their relative proportions.

Comment: Have a look how researchers are studying this  with lattice QCD  https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07916  https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05522